# CSS3 Transform turns text gray during transition?

Tags: html, css, transform, transition

I have no idea what's going on here, but it turns my font inside my paragraph gray DURING the transition. Any ideas? The transform works fine, but also decides to reformat my text inside my paragraph box?

EDIT: Still a problem in Safari (OSX)

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px gray;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #2183de;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 22px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px black;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out
}

.box:hover {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

#main a {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box" id="one">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="boxpara">
        <p class="boxparapadding">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elit tempor et labore dolor do sit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Which browser and OS ? Works fine on chrome (OS X) http://jsfiddle.net/Naemy/CGCEz/

Comment: Its decided it will fix itself. I'm not sure what was causing the problem. Thanks :] - Happens in safari.

Comment: what is your styling for `a`?

Comment: a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}


#main a{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 display: block;
}

Comment: did you try adding `color: white;` to `a` tag?

Comment: Yes, iv'e also applied it to all of #main children

Comment: that's weird because the text is still in white after the transition on my safari. and of course i added `a {color: white;}`

Comment: It's during the transition, not after.

Comment: I would bet that what you see is the text-shadow: gray. In a text that's being resized it's difficult to tell what is text and what is shadow. (And can be animated differently depending on the browser). To make the test, change the text shadow to another color and see what happens

Comment: I've not tried changing it to another colour, however I have removed it and still didn't work.